# Rails facebook Iframe app error: InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, heroku

I get this error when I acccess my facebook iframe app:

```
The change you wanted was rejected.

Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.
```

Heroku logs:

```
2011-06-05T08:30:41+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/facebook/" for xxxx
03 at 2011-06-05 10:30:41 +0200
2011-06-05T08:30:41+00:00 heroku[router]: POST www.vinderhimlen.dk/facebook/ dyn
o=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=39ms bytes=711
2011-06-05T08:30:41+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-06-05T08:30:41+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
 (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
2011-06-05T08:30:41+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-06-05T08:30:41+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-06-05T08:30:41+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-06-05T08:30:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-06-05T08:30:45+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-06-05T08:30:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited

Iceberg@ICEBERG-PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Rails requires a token to be included as a hidden field with every POST.

This protects your app from Cross-Site Request Forgery.

See the Rails [Request Forgery Protection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html#method-i-verify_authenticity_token) documentation.

`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` may be useful for further debugging.

Comment: I have added skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token it still gives the same error

Comment: Try removing `protect_from_forgery` from controllers/application_controller.rb